# Why do we need JOptionPane class to print messages in a separate window?

Tags: java, joptionpane

This question is regarding Java. Why do we need JOptionPane class to print messages in a separate window when I can simply write the messages using System.out.println and take user input via scanner class?

I am a beginner and while programming I could not find any significant use of the class JOptionpane as the messages could otherwise also be printed via S.o.p. Pls tell why is it important to have the class JOptionpane to print messages and take user input.

Comment: Because most users are used to popup windows and forms and don't like to work with a console window.

Comment: You don't *need* it. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: ... because it would be strange when working in Microsoft Word and then having to go to a console window to select font style and size? Not all programs are console-based, some have a graphical user interface (GUI), and when working in a program with a GUI it would be strange to have to enter some information in a console window.

Comment: [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) is actually intended for use in _Swing_ applications - even though they can be used in console applications. For a console application, printing messages (using [System.out.println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out)) is preferable (in my opinion), as is getting user input via class `Scanner` (again, in a console application). In other words, for a console application, you do not need to use `JOptionPane`.